# How would you do this tricky subsetting in R?

Tags: r, indexing, subset

This question might have a simple answer, but I can't figure out how to do it. I'd like to subset a data frame in a manner that is not straightforward.

I have a data frame with 4 columns that express the results of an experiment. The first column has the subject number, the second the item number, the third the type of measure that was taken and the fourth the recorded reading time. I would like to replace the 0 values in the `Value` column but only in specific conditions. To make this concrete, here is the data frame:

```
Subject = c(rep("S1",6), rep("S2",6))       #two subjects
Item    = rep(c(rep("I1",3),rep("I2",3)),2) #two items for each subject
Measure = rep(c("ff","fp","tt"),4)          #three different measures for each item
Value   = c(0,33,21,2,45,66,78,4,3,0,25,67) #reading times
df      = data.frame(Subject,Item,Measure,Value)
df

   Subject Item Measure Value
1       S1   I1      ff     0
2       S1   I1      fp    33
3       S1   I1      tt    21
4       S1   I2      ff     2
5       S1   I2      fp    45
6       S1   I2      tt    66
7       S2   I1      ff    78
8       S2   I1      fp     4
9       S2   I1      tt     3
10      S2   I2      ff     0
11      S2   I2      fp    25
12      S2   I2      tt    67
```

**This is the tricky part!** I want to get all cases where **ff** was 0, and to modify my data frame in the following manner: for *only* the first fixation and first-pass measures (**ff** and **fp**), I'd like to overwrite the existing values in `Value` with NAs, creating a data frame that looks like the one below. The rest of the data frame should remain unchanged. How would you achieve this in a simple manner? Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

```
Subject = c(rep("S1",6), rep("S2",6))
Item    = rep(c(rep("I1",3),rep("I2",3)),2)
Measure = rep(c("ff","fp","tt"),4)
Value   = c("NA","NA",21,2,45,66,78,4,3,"NA","NA",67)
dfnew   = data.frame(Subject,Item,Measure,Value)  
dfnew
    Subject Item Measure Value
1       S1   I1      ff    NA
2       S1   I1      fp    NA
3       S1   I1      tt    21
4       S1   I2      ff     2
5       S1   I2      fp    45
6       S1   I2      tt    66
7       S2   I1      ff    78
8       S2   I1      fp     4
9       S2   I1      tt     3
10      S2   I2      ff    NA
11      S2   I2      fp    NA
12      S2   I2      tt    67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like something that would be much easier in wide format than long format. How about something like this? You could resort the final data frame if order was important.

```
library(reshape2)
d2 <- dcast(Subject + Item ~ Measure, data=df, value.var="Value")
d2
##   Subject Item ff fp tt
## 1      S1   I1  0 33 21
## 2      S1   I2  2 45 66
## 3      S2   I1 78  4  3
## 4      S2   I2  0 25 67
k <- d2$ff==0
d2$ff[k] <- d2$fp[k] <- NA
melt(d2)
## 1       S1   I1       ff    NA
## 2       S1   I2       ff     2
## 3       S2   I1       ff    78
## 4       S2   I2       ff    NA
## 5       S1   I1       fp    NA
## 6       S1   I2       fp    45
## 7       S2   I1       fp     4
## 8       S2   I2       fp    NA
## 9       S1   I1       tt    21
## 10      S1   I2       tt    66
## 11      S2   I1       tt     3
## 12      S2   I2       tt    67
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `which`:

```
idx <- with(df, which(Measure=="ff" & Value==0))
df[idx, "Value"] <- NA
idx <- Filter(function(i) df[i, "Measure"]=="fp", idx+1)
df[idx, "Value"] <- NA
```

Comment: thanks Karsten! But your code will replace all the fp measures in the data frame (= 4 rows). And what I need is to **only** replace the value in fp **if** ff had a value of 0 (that is, only 2 rows should have NA for fp, not 4)

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What you mean (I guess) is 'only replace the value of `df$Value` with `NA` if `df$Measure == "fp"` and if the previous row has `df$Measure == "ff"`and that same row has `df$Value == 0`'? I would need a loop for that.

Comment: Yes, thanks vaettchen, that is what I meant. Or more exactly, 'only replace the value of df$Value with NA if `df$Measure == "fp"` **or** `df$Measure == "ff"` and the previous row was `df$Measure == "ff"` and `df$Value == 0`. How would you do the loop?

Comment: @Karsten W: thanks Karsten! I was trying to avoid using `idx+1` to not make that assumption, but that solution works so unless I get a better one I will use it.

Comment: If someone else has a suggestion that does not rely on **fp** always appearing in the row following **ff** please let me know.